# PIG - org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer - DataStreamer Exception java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

While running pig script, I'm getting the following error.

```
[DataStreamer for file /tmp/temp2077618004/tmp-1307487579/ivy-2.4.0.jar block BP-793676657-10.160.0.22-1603153879591:blk_1073742491_1667] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer - DataStreamer Exception
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:772)
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.
```